# PHP heavy task in background

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I'm building a script to generate thousands of PDF pages but the memory consuming will affect the server's perfomance. As this is not a prioritary task (this generation can take hours, as long as it doesn't affect the webserver) what is the best approach for this problem?

I've seen some implementations of **pthread** but I would have to install also the ZTS. [pthreadPHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php)

Don't really know if this is the right approach for my problem. 
Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid installing pcntl or pthread, simply move the operation to a cron job (with file locking to prevent duplicate processes from running) or a never ending service to process them. Your main application would leave behind the meta data needed to generate the PD while the service runs separately from your main app and can be throttled.

Comment: yes, i could store the metadata needed in DB, but with that approach how could I manager resource consumption so it doesn't affect the main web server?

Comment: Keep in mind that this service or cron job would probably be initially written for handling pdf creation serially, one at a time. This will be the lowest amount of system resources that could be used, if it is too much you'll have to look into getting another node to process these. My feeling is that you may even want to scale up a bit, and get n processes running simultaneously to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) which can allow you to offload the PDF generation process to a completely separate server (or group of servers, gearmand itself is really just a job dispatcher).  The worker scripts can be written in many different languages, including PHP (so if you're already using some PDF Generation library written in PHP, you can still use it).  See also http://gearman.org/

Comment: Thanks, but if the server is the same, can I still manage the memory consumption so it doesn't affect the webserver?

Comment: You can set the web server up to also be the job server and also be the worker server.  Both the job server and worker server will run in separate processes, but will share the same hardware limitations (you won't be able to guarantee that a spike in web traffic during a long-running memory intensive process won't cause issues). Thats why my recommendation would be to compeltely offload it to a separate machine.

Comment: As a followup, you can however manage those processes separately with whatever process management tool you have access to